# Codebuild not installing PHP packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

My codebuild has been working well till today. It's failing with the following errors:

```
Reading state information... 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xml 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-xml' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xmlrpc 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-xmlrpc' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-zip 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-zip' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mysql 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mysql' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mbstring 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mbstring' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mcrypt 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mcrypt' 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-gd
```

what could be the issue?
Please note that the builds have been working well with this setup. There was no change in the buildspec file.

This is what I tried:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
 install:
   commands:
     - |

         apt-get install -y software-properties-common

         export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
         apt-get update

         LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

```
version: 0.2
phases:
 install:
   commands:
     - |

         apt-get install -y software-properties-common

         export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
         apt-get update

         LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
         apt-get update
         apt-get install -y php7.1 \
                  php7.1-xml \
                  php7.1-xmlrpc \
                  php7.1-zip \
                  php7.1-mysql \
                  php7.1-mbstring \
                  php7.1-mcrypt \
                  php7.1-gd \
                  php7.1-opcache \
                  php7.1-dom \
                  php7.1-bcmath \
                  php7.1-curl \
                  unzip \
                  nasm
```

I expected the php packages to be installed normally as it has been the case.

Answer (score 4):

This was an issue with the base image I was using, which was on Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ended support as of April 2019, and from the ondrej repository there is no repo folder that matches ubuntu 14.04.

I had to switch my base image to aws/codebuild/standard:2.0, which fixed my problem.

Comment: I was getting this on aws/codebuild/standard:2.0. but I've since moved over to aws/codebuild/standard:4.0 (it's been a while) and removed the hack mentioned by @sixfive and it's working now.

Answer (score 3):

When you switch to aws/codebuild/standard:2.0 it provides you with Ubuntu 18. You also have to supply a runtime like

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.3
```

I found that AWS put their PHP ini in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ but when you install extensions the ini gets put into /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini - so you have to join the non-standard to the standard so the extension files are found.

This can be solved by adding the standard path to an ini file as follows:

```
touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini
echo extension_dir="/usr/lib/php/20180731/" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini
echo extension=gd.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini
Running command php -m
```

The final buildspec.yml looks like this (with some debug so you can see the before and after, and the contents of the extra_config.ini:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.3
    commands:
      - php -v
      - php -m
      - lsb_release -a
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install -y php7.3-gd  php7.3-xdebug
      - ls /usr/lib/php/20180731
      - touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini
      - "echo extension_dir=\"/usr/lib/php/20180731/\" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini"
      - "echo extension=gd.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini"
      - "echo zend_extension=xdebug.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini"  
      - cat /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini
      - php -m
```

Comment: It's a bizarre situation @AlexBarker - AWS said 'the build is open source so you can see how it works there'. As soon as we get Ubuntu 19 they will go change the directory at huge inconvenience to us all.

Comment: I have tried your solution here, and well, this /usr/lib/php lib folder is not there... find / -name simplexml.so -print returns nothing.  It looks like the only way to get a usable installation of PHP is to use the NodeJS runtime, even if you don't need it, and install PHP manually via the package manager or roll-your-own container.

Comment: Getting error `Running command touch /usr/local/bin/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini`
`touch: cannot touch '/usr/local/bin/php/conf.d/extra_config.ini': No such file or directory`

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am getting the same error too. My buildspec file has been working with this for the past 6 months.

Comment: @Majid I was able to make it run by Code Build -> APP -> Edit Environment -> Override Image and selecting "aws/codebuild/standard:2.0-1.12.0" instead of "Always use the latest image for this runtime version". So it breaks with new new image versions but works on old version.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to update this question because the accepted answer here does not seem to work for me, and even if it did, it is a very brittle solution.  The PHP installation proved by AWS for Ubuntu 18.04 (v2) appears to have been compiled from source along with all of the other supported "runtime-versions" and then dumped into /usr/local.  If you look in this folder, you will immediately notice that you got ALL of the runtime versions, regardless of which you specified in your buildspec file.  This begs the question, why is the runtime-version required or even included in the buildspec file?  I will assume that AWS does this to pretend they have more features and a more sophisticated system then they really do.

So, how do you get a working version of PHP?  The following is part of a buildspec.yml file I am using.  You can pick any runtime-versions you want, we have already established that this parameter doesn't do anything.  Then you need to remove all of the PHP garbage AWS included in /usr/local/bin because that location comes before /usr/bin in the environment PATH. I assume this was done by Amazon to make this process as difficult as possible.  Now that you do not have PHP in the path anymore, you can install the package managers version of PHP via `apt-get install -y php7.2-cli php7.2-zip`.  Finally, do not forget to run `phpenmod` for the modules installed to ensure they are enabled.

```
version: 0.2

run-as: root

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 8
    commands:
      - rm -f /usr/local/bin/php*
      - rm -f /usr/local/bin/phar*
      - rm -f /usr/local/bin/pear*
      - rm -f /usr/local/bin/pecl*
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get upgrade -y
      - apt-get install -y php7.2-cli php7.2-zip
      - phpenmod zip
```

Comment: It is pretty bad that this is the only way to get this to work, but nothing else worked for me, so I guess I'll go with this..

Comment: I ended up using the ubuntu:bionic container directly and connected it to AWS which was less hackie than trying to get their machine image to do anything useful.